# Posting the selected html option attribute via php

Tags: php

Posting the selected html option attribute via php..Here is my html code and I'm trying to select one option from the event-drop down menu, but really finding it hard to configure with php variable $event. Any help will be much appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
    <div>
    <h4>Event</h4>
    <p class="cd-select icon">
    <select class="budget">
    <option value="0">Select Occasion</option>
    <option value="1">alpha</option>
    <option value ="2">Bravo</option>
    <option value="3">Charlie</option>
    <option value="4">Delta</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    </div>
```

PHP version

```
    $event = $_POST['selected'];
```

Comment: Your select element needs a name attribute `<select class="budget" name="event">` will give `$_POST['event']`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP form fields are posted with their name. In your case you'd have to add the name attribute to the select.

```
<select class="budget" name="selected">
<option value="0">Select Occasion</option>
<option value="1">alpha</option>
<option value ="2">Bravo</option>
<option value="3">Charlie</option>
<option value="4">Delta</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, it's returning the numerical value bind within the 'value' attribute, not the actual value it's meant to send. Which is alpha for 1 and so on...

Comment: That's because you've set the value to 0, 1 etc. the text Alpha is not a value that is submitted but simply the text you wish the user to see. Either check the number and map against the matching text value in your processing script (with a switch statement for example) or change the value to match the text you in the select options. I'd go for the first option so the comparison is simpler.